# Multi-Column ComboBox Controls for Winforms

Tags: .net, datagrid, controls, combobox, multiple-columns

Please recommend some Multi-Column ComboBox control for Winforms application in .net. Better if they are free.

I found [Syncfusion - Multi-column-combo-box](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/windows-forms/tools/multi-column-combo-box) it can show datagrid which is bound to datasource but it is not free.

**EDIT:** There is an awesome control used in inFlow Inventroy, please also tell if you know something like this

> [image: inFlow Inventory multi-column combox]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Controls from other answers and those which I found myself
[DevExpress - GridLookUpEdit](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/GridLookUpEdit.xml)
[image]

---

[DevExpress - LookUpEdit](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Editors/editors/LookUpEdit.xml)
[image]

---

[Infragistics - WinCombo](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/wincombo.aspx)

---

[Syncfusion - Multi-column-combo-box](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/windows-forms/tools/multi-column-combo-box)
[image]

---

[CodeProject - Auto Complete Multi Column ComboBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/MultiColComboSugtionBox.aspx)
[image]

---

[CodeProject - Customizable ComboBox Drop-Down](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/CustomDDComboBox.aspx) *this one is good*
[image]

---

[CodeProject - Multi Column ComboBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/multicolumncombo.aspx)
[image]

---

[CodeProject - Flat-MultiColumn Combobox with Autocomplete](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/MultiColumnFlatCombo.aspx)
[image]

---

[CodeProject - Multicolumn Combobox with Additional Format Conditions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/Multicolumn_ComboBox.aspx)
[image]

---

[CodeProject - Searchable MultiColumn ComboBox with Linked TextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/MultiColumnComboBoxLinked.aspx)
[image]

---

[Binary Mission - Advanced ComboBox .NET](http://www.binarymission.co.uk/Products/winforms/combobbox-wf.html)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The basic technique is same: to show multi-column structure (grid or listview etc. in drop down). Here is nice example on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/MultiColComboSugtionBox.aspx) which can get you started into it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not free, but http://www.infragistics.com makes a bunch of controls, one of which is a multi-column combo box.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Devexpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/) controls. But they are not free.

Answer (score 1):

Another one (not free though) is from a company called "Binarymission" - www.binarymission.co.uk

Comment: Wow it is awesome, though not free :)

Comment: I know, but i got it for $99. They seem to be running an offer now. The entire kit of controls for $99 ;)