# How to add multi columns and their column headers to a combbox in dotnet winforms?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, combobox

When click on a combobox, it's Dropdown should be displayed and there should be two columns. Each column should have a column header. I want to achieve this in vb.net winforms. Is it possible? Can anyone suggest an idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-Column ComboBox Controls for Winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899169/multi-column-combobox-controls-for-winforms)

Comment: This isn't possible using the standard `Microsoft ComboBox`. I personally use the `Infragistics` suite, but it isn't free, if that's important.